# How can I efficiently identify the a natural division point between two sets of numbers?

Tags: php, arrays, math, categories, intersection

I have two datasets (A & B). They each have 1000 numbers.

99% of the time: A < 5 <= B

However, 1% of the time B < 5 < A.

If the division point is unknown - `x` - how can one determine `x` with any given dataset?

Obviously `Max(A)` and `Min(B)` are misleading. And I'd prefer not to loop through the entire range (or even just between Min(B) and Max(A)) guessing and identifying the greatest probable division point.

```
Sample Dataset

A 1
A 1
A 1
A 2
B 2 <--anomoly
A 3
A 3
A 3
A 4
A 5 <--anomoly
B 5 <--division, or `x`
B 5
B 5
B 5
A 6 <--anomoly
B 7
B 8
B 8
B 8
B 9
B 9
B 10
B 10
```

Assume another pair of datasets exists (C & D). How can I find the point where C becomes D after allowing for a certain threshold of anomalies.

What do you recommend?

Here's a rough "guessing" strategy. I'd like to get the same without a "guessing" loop.

```
$maxProbable = 0;
$pointOfDivision = 0;
for ($i = Min($b); $i <= Max($a); $i++) {
    // get probability $i is in_array($a)
    $countBelow = below($i,$a); // assume function returns count of $a items below $i
    $countAbove = above($i,$b); // assume function returns count of $b items above $i
    $probBelow = $countBelow/count($a);
    $probAbove = $countAbove/count($b);
    if (($probBelow+$probAbove) > $maxProbable) {
        $maxProbable = $probBelow+$probAbove;
        $pointOfDivision = $i;
    }
}
echo $pointOfDivision;
```

Comment: Assuming this is homework, what class is it for? That can often influence the desired solution

Comment: Actually, not homework. Just a use case. I'm reviewing an reporting dashboard that requires staff to tune different items throughout the day. There has to be a way to automate the tuning. This is merely a super-simplified use case that hopefully points me in the right direction.

Comment: This sounds like a mixture model problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [well-known problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_classification) in statistics and machine learning: given a number of labeled datapoints, determine the likeliest label for a new datapoint. In the 1D case it often boils down to determining a threshold value x and saying "anything below x is has label A" and "anything above x has label B."

There are many algorithms: you could use for example [logistic regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression), [neural networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_networks), or [support vector machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine). The choice of algorithm depends on what can be assumed of the data and on what tools and libraries you have available; for example SVM is apparently tricky to implement yourself.

If you told how the data is generated or if it comes from a well known statistical distribution there might be a shortcut to a solution that's less complex but still adequate.

Comment: Thanks Joni. Each of those looks a lot more complex than expected. Can you suggest a strategy for a simple (1D?) case?  The data is generated hourly and if dumped into excel and sorted, it's very obvious (for a human) to tell where the division point is. Today people drag around sliders in this custom reporting tool to manually identify this point. This seems ripe for automation. The case above isn't too far off my actual use case. Just with a lot more numbers, but still with only two labels and very few anomalies.

Comment: How few anomalies, like 5% max?

Comment: Yes, under 5% is very fair.  Mostly under 2%.

Comment: In that case you can remove the top and bottom 2.5% of each dataset, so there's no overlap in what remains. Set the threshold to a point between the datasets by finding the maximum and minimum.

Comment: Not bad. I did what you said and averaged the remaining max & min. In my actual dataset I found that it trended a little low, but only added one item (~0.1%) of "noise" that a human would've not had. I'll play around with this strategy and see where it takes me. Thanks again.